# HERE map set marker from MySql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, here-api

I want to fetch values from database. how i will achieve this? Please help

```
    addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:33.6844, lng:73.0479},
    '<div>PH: 7.5 ' +
    '</div><div>Temp: 24 <br>Conduct: 600</div>');
```

right now it is hardcoded but i need these values (lat,long,ph,temp,conduct) from mysql database.. database is already created just needed to fetch and set marker on map.

```js
function addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
  var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
  // add custom data to the marker
  marker.setData(html);
  group.addObject(marker);
}


function addInfoBubble(map) {
  var group = new H.map.Group();

  map.addObject(group);

  // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:33.6844, lng:73.0479},
    '<div>PH: 7.5 ' +
    '</div><div>Temperture: 24 <br>Conductivity: 600</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will use PHP as your server-side script, you can go to here: [PHP Connect to MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) to know how to connect with your MySQL server, then you can fetch data using this: [PHP Select Data From MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)